# Find closest value in an array List with linq?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I've a list like this:

```
    public static List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>();
```

[image]

In addition I have also a variable named X. X can take any value. I want to find closest and smaller value to X in `list[?][1]`. For example:

If X is 1300, I want to take list index: 1. Or if X is 700, I want to take index: 0. How can I do this via linq? Or, is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it you want returned? The index? The value?

Comment: (1) Does it have to use Linq? (2) As flindeberg asked, what do you want returned? The inner list? The inner list + an index to the found element in that list? An outer list index + the inner list index to the found element in that list? Or something else?

Comment: I want to take closest value's index to X variable. As my question, if X = 700, result should be 0. Because 480 is closest and smaller value to X  and  it's list index is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in a following way (snippet assumes, that list is not empty)

```
var x = 700;
var result = list.Select((subList, idx) => new { Value = subList[1], Idx = idx })
                 .Where(elem => elem.Value < x)
                 .Select(elem => new { Diff = Math.Abs(x - elem.Value), elem.Idx })
                 .OrderBy(elem => elem.Diff).FirstOrDefault();

if (result != null)
{
    return result.Idx;
}

// case - there is no such index
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. However it finds closest value but not smaller. For example: X = 3889, list[7][1] = 3630, list[8][1] = 4080. So, the query find 8. But it should be 7. What can I do for this?

Comment: @team16sah yeah, I ve not noticed - please check now (after edit)

Comment: As it is, the code seems to work only if the values in the arrays are pre-sorted smallest to largest.

Comment: @madd0 array sort doesn't matter. the OP wants to look inside first index in array. (list[?][1]). There is not info that he wants to search in whole array.

Comment: There is a problem. The result takes null in my sample.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear: the arrays must be sorted within the list by their second element. In his example, if you move element 0 to the end of the list and X = 700, Idx is still 0

Comment: Although X = 480 and list[0][1] = 480, result takes null. Still.

Comment: @team16sah you have wrote "smaller" not smaller or equal. If you want to include equal, just change `elem.Value < x` to `elem.Value <= x`.

Comment: You are right. I've also forget to wrote one thing. If there is no smaller or equal value to X, I should take first index of list.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a Linq solution, but I think that a non-Linq solution is also good.

If you are interested in a non-Linq solution, here's one (it *does* use Linq in one place, but really that's stretching the point!).

The main method of interest, `FindClosestSmaller()`, returns a `Tuple` where `.Item1` is the index of the outer list that contains the closest value that is less than or equal to a target value, and `.Item2` is the index of that match in the inner array.

If no value less than or equal to the target value is found, `.Item1` and `.Item2` will both be zero.

Note that `FindClosestSmaller()` takes a parameter of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`, which means you can use it with most collection types and you aren't just limited to, say, `List<int[]>`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var ints1 = new [] { 1,  480,  749, 270 };
            var ints2 = new [] { 1,  810, 1080, 271 };
            var ints3 = new [] { 1, 7680, 7949, 271 };

            var intLists = new List<int[]> {ints1, ints2, ints3};

            test(intLists, 1300);
            test(intLists,  700);
            test(intLists,  480);
            test(intLists,    0);
        }

        private static void test(List<int[]> values, int target)
        {
            var result = FindClosestSmaller(values, target);
            Console.WriteLine("Target {0} found: Outer index = {1}, Inner index = {2}", target, result.Item1, result.Item2);
        }

        public static Tuple<int, int> FindClosestSmaller(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> sequences, int target)
        {
            int closest = int.MaxValue;

            int closestInner = 0; // Setting these to zero means we take the first element of the
            int closestOuter = 0; // first list if no smaller element is found.

            int outer = 0;

            foreach (var sequence in sequences)
            {
                int inner = 0;

                foreach (int distance in sequence.Select(value => target - value))
                {
                    if ((distance >= 0) && (distance < closest))
                    {
                        closest      = distance;
                        closestInner = inner;
                        closestOuter = outer;
                    }

                    ++inner;
                }

                ++outer;
            }

            return new Tuple<int, int>(closestOuter, closestInner);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for clean code. Linq solutions are very ugly & hard to maintain & hard to understand, this is not the place for linq.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by flatten elements to a new anonymous type where `index` is the index in the outer array, and item is the value in the inner array:

Assume input and a desired target value:

```
var target = 20;
var input = (new int[][]{new int[]{1,2,3}, new int[]{4,7,8}, new int[]{5,4}});
```

Then flattening would be

```
var tmp = input.SelectMany((x, y) => x.Select(item => 
         new {index = y, item = item, delta = Math.Abs(target - item)}));
```

Now you can find the optimal delta:

```
var bestDelta = tmp.Min(x => x.delta);
```

And from this it is simple to find the best match:

```
var result = tmp.FirstOrDefault(x => x.delta == bestDelta);
```

Or if you prefer simply to get the index:

```
var index = tmp.Where(x => x.delta == bestDelta).Select(x => x.index).First();
```

This could be rewritten to the oneliner:

```
var result = input.SelectMany((x, y) => 
     x.Select(item => new {index = y, item = item, delta = Math.Abs(target - item)}))
     .OrderBy(x => x.delta).Select(x => x.index).First();
```

But I tend to find the other solution more readable.